# Android: Parse the Nested JSON Array and JSON Object

Tags: android, arrays, json, wordpress-json-api

I have this JSON content from a WordPress Site

```
"posts": [
 {

    "id": 67986,
    "type": "post",
    "title": "Launching New eBooks",
    "thumbnail_images": {
           "full": {
                  "url": "http://www.marineinsight.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/boiler-featured.png",
                  "width": 700,
                  "height": 500
                   },

           "medium": {
                   "url": "http://www.marineinsight.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/boiler-featured-300x214.png",
                   "width": 300,
                   "height": 214
                    },
          } 
  }
```

I want to fetch the `url` from `medium` to display as image. After referring to some SO questions, I have made this code and tried to go into the loop. But somehow i get the entire `thumbnail_images`

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("posts");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray bigImage = object.getJSONArray("thumbnail_images");
                    for (int j = 0; j < bigImage.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject tiObj = bigImage.getJSONObject(j);
                        JSONArray tiMed = tiObj.getJSONArray("medium");
                        for (int k = 0; k < tiMed.length(); k++) {
                            JSONObject tiMedU = tiMed.getJSONObject(i);
                           String imageURL = tiMedU.getString("url");

                        }

                    }


                    actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("title"));
                    actor.setDescription(object.getString("url"));
                    actor.setImage(imageURL);
                    actor.setDob(object.getString("content"));

                    actorsList.add(actor);
                }
```

Not able to figure out whats wrong in the loops above. Any help wld be great. Thanks

Comment: `thumbnail_images` is not `JSONArray` it's and `JSONObject`

Comment: jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("thumbnail_images").getJSONObject("medium").getString("url")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this

```
 JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
            jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("posts");

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject bigImage = object.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                    JSONObject tiMed = bigImage.getJSONObject("medium");
                    String imageURL = tiMed.getString("url");
                    }

                }


                actor = new Actors();

                actor.setName(object.getString("title"));
                actor.setDescription(object.getString("url"));
                actor.setImage(imageURL);
                actor.setDob(object.getString("content"));

                actorsList.add(actor);
            }
```

Comment: This doesnt work.. shows error at `getJSONObject(j)`

Comment: can you send me URL so that I can send you exact code

Comment: use this
   JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
   JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("posts");
   for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject bigImage = object.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
    JSONObject tiMed = bigImage.getJSONObject("medium");
    String imageURL = tiMed.getString("url");
    String width = tiMed.getString("width");
    String height = tiMed.getString("height");
    System.out.println("imageURL : " + imageURL);
   }

Comment: Yes.. that worked.. thanks :).. why dont you update your answer so that i can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Try using Gson lib from google to parse Json response. It is fast, simple and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).
getJSONObject("thumbnail_images").
getJSONObject("medi‌​um").getString("url")


JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    //JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                    System.out.println("apk----------------"+jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("thumbnail_images").getJSONObject("medium").getString("url"));
                }
```

Comment: this code returns `org.json.JSONException: No value for medi‌​um`

Comment: Are you sure thumbnail_images is jsonobject and not json array

Comment: Still the same.. just to confirm.. i am writing it like this `actor.setImage(object.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images").getJSONObject("medi‌​um").getString("url"));`

Comment: seems like your problem is solved but above solution also works I have added code check it I guess you were doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("http://10.0.0.4:8000/login/?format=json&name="+username.getText().toString()+"&password="+pwd.getText().toString());
      JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(response);//Json Array
      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
      {
      JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);//Json Array To Json Object
      Jenter code hereSONObject jsonObj2 = json_data.getJSONObject("fields");
      usertype = jsonObj2.getString("usertype");
      email = jsonObj2.getString("email");
      }
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```